# Can't get appsession setting in HAProxy to work

Tags: haproxy

My haproxy.cfg has a frontend which then redirects to a bunch of backends,

here is a sample backend (note that connections into this have already been through [stunnel to rip out SSL](http://www.stunnel.org/):

```
backend thenameofit        
reqadd          X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
reqadd          FRONT_END_HTTPS:\ on
server myserver1 serverhostnamex:80 weight 1 maxconn 5000 check
server myserver2 serverhostnamey:80 weight 1 maxconn 5000 check
appsession ASP.NET_SessionId len 100 timeout 3h
```

I'm sure I'm simply missing a setting somewhere, but I must be missing it when reading the [config documentation](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/download/1.4/doc/configuration.txt).

I'm using HAProxy 1.4.13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also need to use `cookie ASP.NET_SessionID prefix`.